Compiling for loop in rust-gpu?
I am using rust-gpu to compile some crates I had into SPIRV to use in my shaders. It seems that it is struggling to compile regular for loops, for example:
impl<const N: usize> DDA<N>
{
    pub fn new(
        position: [f32; N],
        box_corner_position: [f32; N],
        direction: [f32; N],
        index: [isize; N],
        cell_width: f32,
    ) -> Self
    {
        // Initialize the step size for each dimension from the direction vector.
        // Moving by `direction[i] * step_size[i]` is guaranteed to move the point by
        // exactly one cell width.
        let mut step_size = [0.0; N];
        for i in 0..N
        {
            step_size[i] = cell_width / direction[i].abs();
        }
   }
}

Yields:
error: cannot offset a pointer to an arbitrary element
   --> /home/makogan/rust_never_engine/crates/iterators/src/raster_line.rs:30:18
    |
30  |         for i in 0 as usize..N as usize
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |

What could I do here as an alternative if I want to stay as close to this syntax as possible.

It'd probably be good to pose this question to the maintainers. I know GPU code can be... picky... about loops but I don't know enough about how rustgpu transforms the code to know what can be done about it in this case.
